# Problems in c# code (Noob)

Tags: c#, .net

My program closes before giving results and the age differences are wrong.

I've checked everywhere and they said use `Console.Read()`, `Console.ReadLine()`, or `Console.ReadKey()` which I did before they even said that but it still doesn't work. Someone else said use `System("PAUSE")` but that just gives me an error.

It also said when I entered 21 as an age that 21 - 12 = 38???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static String name;
        static int age;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the application!");
            Console.Write("What's your name? ");

            // Setting the name string to the line read from the console.
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("\n So how old are you " + name + "? ");

            // Doing the same thing we did last time with the age.
            age = Console.Read();

            compareAges();
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void compareAges()
        {
            if(age < 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I'm older than you! I'm 12.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if(age == 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We're the same age!!!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                int ageDifference = age - 12;
                Console.WriteLine("You're " + ageDifference + " years older than me!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry if I made some indention errors here but the actual code's indention is correct.

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Comment: Use `age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` as console.read() gives you character and Its too clumsy the code

Comment: Debugger says nothing. Tushar Gupta, Andy Korneyev, and Dmitry Bychenko answered it.

Comment: You could have given better question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the

```
age = Console.Read();
```

well, `Console.Read()` reads *one symbol* only - character `2` in your case that´s `50` int, and you have

```
  '2' - 12 == 38 // '2' == 50
```

remedy: read the *whole string* which is `"21"` in your case

```
  String line = Console.ReadLine();
```

then *parse* it into integer:

```
  // Parse() is the simplest; TryParse() is a better: 
  // what if a user entered "bla-bla-bla"?
  age = int.Parse(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
age = Console.Read();
```

Here you just set age to ASCII code of input character since `Read` reads one symbol from console and returns it's ASCII code.

It should be instead

```
age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Jeez so much hate from people -6! Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: @josephcoggins very interesting. Are you sure you're exactly copied string I've suggested? Note - it should be `ReadLine()`, not `Read()` there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it. Maybe not the best, but it works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1{
    class Program{
        public static int Main(){
            Program.determineAgeDifference dta = new Program.determineAgeDifference();

            string[] input = new string[2];

            Console.Write("So, what's your name?\n\n>> ");
            input[0] = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Clear();

            Console.Write("How old are you?\n\n>> ");
            input[1] = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(dta(int.Parse(input[1].TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ')));
            Console.ReadLine();

            return 0;
        }
        private string determineAgeDifference(int age){
             string returnValue = "";

            if (age < 12){
                returnValue = "I'm older than you. I'm 12!";
            }
            else if (age == 12){
                returnValue = "We are the same age!!!";
            }
            else{
                returnValue = ("You're " + (age - 12).ToString() + "Years older than me!");
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```